# Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_users()

Tags: users, fatal-error

Is there any reason for getting this error?

I tested a couple of installations so far.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Which wordpress version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's WordPress 3.1 function - so you're probably testing it on older versions.

Comment: Yep. I had to use `get_users_of_blog()`instead. I will never understand why functions change name with new updates. It is the best way to break stuff.

Comment: @Mirko: If you want to prevent that, don't upgrade to the next non-minor version. Otherwise you need to test everything first in the period that's given with the last RC candidates for the next non-minor version to theme and plugin developers.

Comment: @hakre. That is right, but most of the times the upgrade final decision is left to the client. He might decide to upgrade just because he read about new features on the web and I cannot avoid it unfortunately...